# Where is my error in this attempt to use jQuery each for elements css setting?

Tags: jquery, css, field, each

I am looking for a better and clear way to set css values for a bunch of elements.

So by doing this in jQuery:

```
$content.css( {
            scale: rescale
        } );
$left_mask
        .css( {
            x: -460,
            opacity: 0,
            scale: bgsy
        } );
$im     .css( {
            x: '-15%'
        } );
$right_mask
        .css( {
            x: 460,
            opacity: 0,
            scale: bgsy
        } );
```

I’d like to achieve something similar to:

```
matrixCss = {
    $content:       { scale: rescale },
    $left_mask:     { x: -460, opacity: 0, scale: bgsy },
    $im:            { x: '-15%' },
    $right_mask:    { x: 460, opacity: 0, scale: bgsy }
};
// set base states
$.each( matrixCss, function( $el, baseStates ) {
    $el.css( baseStates );
} );
```

1. What am I doing wrong here?
2. Is there an even better and shorter way to achieve this?
   I’d love to use my matrixCss field on many places sometimes with animate also.

Comment: is this dynamic css? i mean, could you use classes instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$content`, ... are property names and do not refer to the variables with the name `$content`, ... .

you would need to do something like:

```
matrixCss = [
   { obj: $content, css: { scale: rescale }},
];
```

(If `rescale` is not a variable then you need to write it in quotes `'rescale'`)

```
matrixCss.forEach(function(item) {
   item.obj.css(item.css);
});
```

Or with ES6:

```
matrixCss.forEach( item => item.obj.css(item.css) );
```

Comment: Brillant. Perfect. Works like a charm. I will try to get some deeper understanding of this. Thanks!! Rescale is in fact a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/hdbuzLm2/

In the jQuery.each method, the first parameter passed ('$el') is each key of the object. So for your example, the first iteration would be the string '$content'.

In order for the jQuery css method to work, you need to first create a jQuery object. So if your element's id is '$content', you need to create

```
$('#$content').css( baseStates );
```

However, jQuery doesn't like '$' at the beginning of the id. So you need to change your ids to not start with it. So if you change your matrixCss so the keys are

```
matrixCss = {
    content:       { scale: 'rescale' },
    left_mask:     { x: -460, opacity: 0, scale: 'bgsy' },
    im:            { x: '-15%' },
    right_mask:    { x: 460, opacity: 0, scale: 'bgsy' }
};
```

then the $.each loop should look like this:

```
$.each( matrixCss, function( $el, baseStates ) {
    $('#' + $el).css(baseStates);
} );
```

BTW, another way might be to just create another set of css properties and change (or add) a class name on your elements.

```
// css definition
#content .alternate { scale: 'rescale' }
#left_mask .alternate {x: -460, opacity: 0, scale: 'bgsy'}

// js - add 'alternate' class to elements
$('#content, #left_mask').addClass('alternate');
```

Comment: I will give this a try also. Thanks!